# How to Split the big s3 file into multiple files based on size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to split my s3 file of 50GB into multiple files of 10 GB each. Can we use aws s3 cp commands with additional options to do this ?

Comment: Why do you want to split it? To simplify the upload? Or, something else?

Comment: What is the format of the files? Text? Zip? Do they need to be split at any particular place (eg at the end of a line)? Feel free to edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a part of s3 object by specifying --range using s3api (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html), s3 cmd will not support it, you need to use s3api, s3api supports low-level commands.

if your concerns is to speedup the upload process by parallelising then aws s3 internally does that for you using multipart upload for bigger files.

You can also implement your custom logic using s3api 
(https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-multipart-upload-cli/)

Answer (score 0):

To whoever comes across this similar problem. Here is what worked for me.
I followed the steps from this blog: https://medium.com/swlh/automatic-s3-file-splitter-620d04b6e81c.
But it was splitting based on the number of lines, which was corrupting my CSV, so had to split based on size (using the -C option of the split command)
Here is the modified sh file (run it in an EC2 instance/lambda/AWS Batch):

```
SOURCE_BUCKET=source_bucket
DEST_BUCKET=dest_bucket
FILENAME=file.csv
FILESIZE=10000000000 #~10GB
INFILE=s3://"${SOURCE_BUCKET}"/"${FILENAME}"
OUTFILE=s3://"${DEST_BUCKET}"/"${FILENAME%%.*}"
echo $INFILE, $OUTFILE

echo "Starting S3 File Splitter using file size of "${FILESIZE}" bytes"
echo "Splitting file: "${INFILE}" ..."
FILES=($(aws s3 cp "${INFILE}" - | split -d -C ${FILESIZE} -a4 --filter "aws s3 cp - \"${OUTFILE}_\$FILE.csv\"  | echo \"\$FILE.csv\""))


# This is the return value because it's being sent to stderr (>&2)
echo "{\"success\": true}" >&2
```